# Logos on top bar disappearing on zoom

Tags: css

I have been working on CSS for my blog at http://shaanan.cohney.info/blog/
and the facebook/google+ links I've put up the top disappear when one zooms in.
The behaviour I would like is for it to shrink to fit inside the remaining area.
Do I change it from using float to using left % and right %?

Thanks,
shaananc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make images position fixed & place them using left & top in CSS. Or you can give a margin in percentage to image (left margin for Facebook & right for G+).